# Is the assignment expression a lvalue reference?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
template <typename T> void g(T &&val);
int i = 0; const int ci = i;
g(i = ci);
```

What is the template argument of `g`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per §5.18/1:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. [...]

So, in

```
g(i = ci)
```

the left operand, `i`, is returned and therefore `T` is deduced to `int&`.

You can check this via this snippet:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> 
void g(T &&val) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int&>::value, "Nope");
}

int main() {
    int i = 0; const int ci = i;
    g(i = ci);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb8d006d78558c19)